# Eclipse IDE - Customizing double-click word separators / delimiters?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Mars.

Is it possible to customize the program so that it will treat certain characters as word delimiters when double-clicking on text?

For example, I would like to be able to select text between underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Someone could write a plug-in providing an editor with that level of control, but generally it's the strategy that the developer picked.